# Directed graphs represented with formal grammar

Tags: graph, grammar, context-free-grammar, directed-graph, representation

Is it possible to represent arbitrary directed graphs (with labeled edges) with a formal grammar, for example a context-sensitive grammar?
If it is possible, is there a proof where you can read this up?

Comment: Given that languages exist for representing directed graphs (e.g. [DOT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DOT_language)), I'd say the answer is: yes.

Comment: I'd recommend taking a look at Gremlin as well and the entire Tinkerpop suite: https://github.com/tinkerpop/gremlin/wiki